# Процедурное программирование на Python

Tags: python, дерево, очередь, стек, процедуры

Выполняю задание для вуза, использовать можно только процедурное программирование, без ООП. Нужно реализовать список, очередь, стек, множество и дерево в двух вариантах - на основе статических структур (массивов) и на основе механизма динамических переменных.

Я недавно начал изучать python, возможно ли выполнить это задание на нем? И насколько это целесообразно на фоне С++?

Comment: В Python нет статических структур/массивов, только динамические.